# Using 2D array data instead of table in Vega Lite

Tags: prometheus, vega, vega-lite

I am trying to read data from Prometheus (https://prometheus.io) into Vega Lite.
Prometheus returns its data in a 2D array, like this:

```
[[1, 10], [3, 6], [5, 0], [9, 4], [11, 2]]
```

Is it possible to transform this data in Vega Lite so that it turns into this?

```
[
  {
    "time": 1,
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "time": 3,
    "value": 6,
  },
...
]
```

I have looked at the documentation, and I can see that it's possible to flatten a 1D array, but I couldn't figure out a way to flatten a 2D array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by combining a sequence of [flatten transforms](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/flatten.html) and [calculate transforms](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html). For example ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBnepI3gG1CBGAGhIAYBdMwgZjIDZbCBWMmugTjIBZWJcgCZq1AL7iyIKACcIAOywAzAPayAtkVDKU0KBgVFw0WBLKgAxqkto9B+CahoNAOnwRCNENIg44MgCWGhggUlY2dtChAfgu7qak1D4gfo7I6KHitCAaELIA1o4ogQqh0oaWqmClAOa4IAAeDcqBGChgjlDB5TIAngAOMSAAjmiK3TDdiFnSfS1tHemomClQg8NjE4FTgTNhkkA)):

```
{
  "data": {"values": {"data": [[1, 10], [3, 6], [5, 0], [9, 4], [11, 2]]}},
  "transform": [
    {"flatten": ["data"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.data[0]", "as": "time"},
    {"calculate": "datum.data[1]", "as": "value"}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "time", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice tip! Will save it for future use.